# Wrong value for Fiftness history api from Google

Tags: android, google-api, google-fit

I'm trying to make a simple app which shows the number of calories from a day.
The values received are not similar with what is inside the Fit app from google.
More than that i don't understand why i have values in the future.

```
  DataReadRequest readRequest =
            new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                    .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                    .build();
```

What values i receive when i print the whole result.

```
I/BasicHistoryApi: Range Start: Jul 7, 2018
I/BasicHistoryApi: Range End: Jul 8, 2018
I/BasicHistoryApi: Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: 1
I/BasicHistoryApi: Data returned for Data type: com.google.calories.expended
I/BasicHistoryApi: Data point:
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Type: com.google.calories.expended
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Start: 12:00:18 AM
I/BasicHistoryApi:  End: 12:00:18 AM
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Field: calories Value: 1524.4999
I/BasicHistoryApi: Range Start: Jul 28, 2018
I/BasicHistoryApi: Range End: Jul 29, 2018
I/BasicHistoryApi: Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: 1
I/BasicHistoryApi: Data returned for Data type: com.google.calories.expended
I/BasicHistoryApi: Data point:
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Type: com.google.calories.expended
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Start: 12:00:24 AM
I/BasicHistoryApi:  End: 12:00:24 AM
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Field: calories Value: 1524.4999
I/BasicHistoryApi: Range Start: Jul 23, 2018
I/BasicHistoryApi: Range End: Jul 24, 2018
I/BasicHistoryApi: Number of returned buckets of DataSets is: 1
I/BasicHistoryApi: Data returned for Data type: com.google.calories.expended
I/BasicHistoryApi: Data point:
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Type: com.google.calories.expended
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Start: 12:00:33 AM
I/BasicHistoryApi:  End: 12:00:33 AM
I/BasicHistoryApi:  Field: calories Value: 1524.4999
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually google fit api gives the accurate data for the particular time and it takes some time to reflect that value in Google Fit application.
I have also used their api for calories, number of steps etc so it always give the current data through api

Comment: What do you mean when you are saying "some time to reflect that value"? Also i don't see how i have same result for each day...

Comment: I meant to say that google fit app updates after some time but when we hit their api , they give us the current values. And are you getting the same result for each day ??